# Finding the intersection of tables that use a many-to-many relationship in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get an intersection of two tables that uses two many-to-many tables to relate each other. Example tables as follows:

```
**Discount**                **DiscountRef**                **ProductCat**     **Product**
|DisId| Discount|Amount|    |DisId|RefType|RefId|IsActive|    |ProdId|CatId|    |ProdId|      ProdName|ProdPrice|
+-----+---------+------+    +-----+-------+-----+--------+    +------+-----+    +------+--------------+---------+
|    1|   2% Off|  0.02|    |    1|Product| 9004|       0|    |  9001| 3456|    |  9001|       9" Nail|     0.50|
|    2|  10% Off|  0.10|    |    2|Product| 9002|       0|    |  9002| 3456|    |  9002|    2"x4" Stud|     2.50|
|    3|  25% Off|  0.25|    |    2|   PCat| 3456|       1|    |  9005| 3456|    |  9003|   Claw Hammer|     5.99|
|    4|  2 for 1|  0.50|    |    3|   PCat| 7346|       1|    |  9001| 7346|    |  9004|     Wood Glue|     1.20|
|    5|Clearance|  0.75|    |    3|   PCat| 4455|       1|    |  9003| 7346|    |  9005|6'x4' Dry Wall|    10.39|
                            |    5|Product| 9004|       0|    |  9003| 4455|    |  9006|   Screwdriver|     4.25|
                                                              |  9006| 4455|
```

With these tables I need to get the intersection of Product Categories if there under the same Discount Id. The below table is what I **need** to get:

```
|DisId|ProdId|DisPrice|
+-----+------+--------+
|    2|  9001|    0.45|
|    2|  9002|    2.25|
|    2|  9005|    9.36|
|    3|  9003|    4.50|
```

I have tried a few different ways but can't seem to get to that table. The below SQL returns me the discounts that have more then one category applied to it.

```
SELECT DR.DisId, PC.CatId
FROM DiscountRef DR
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DisId
    FROM DiscountRef
    GROUP BY DisId
    HAVING COUNT(DisId) > 1
) SDR ON SDR.DisId = DR.DisId
INNER JOIN ProductCat PC ON PC.CatId = DR.RefId AND DR.RefType = 'PCat'
GROUP BY DR.DisId, PC.CateId
```

Table Returned:

```
|DisId|CatId|
+-----+-----+
|    3| 7346|
|    3| 4455|
```

Then using the Product Categories Id's with an intersect of Product tables I get the correct amount of product Ids.

```
SELECT P1.ProdId
FROM Product P1
INNER JOIN ProdCat PC1 ON PC1.ProdId = P1.ProdId AND PC1.CategoryId = 7346
INTERSECT
SELECT P2.ProdId
FROM Product P2
INNER JOIN ProdCat PC2 ON PC2.ProdId = P2.ProdId AND PC2.CategoryId = 4455
```

Also a discount can have more then two categories (Narrows down the number of products), and some times there's more then one discount active (discount data is omitted for this but a check will be done).

Any help on how I can get my desired table above?

**EDIT:** If there are multiple DisIds on the DiscountRef table and they happen to be the PCat type they are products that shared in all the categories. Like how Claw Hammer is the only item that appears in both CatId 7346 AND CatId 4455.

Comment: Please clarify what the purpose of column Amount of table **Discount** is used for. Also, please clarify why ProdId 9002 has a DisPrice of 2.25 but at the same time is referenced twice in the table **DiscountRef** (referenced by Product = 9002 and PCat=3456). What would be the rule if both rows would refer to different DisId?

Comment: @Lmu92 I think he mentions that there can be multiple discounts active which may be the reason its referenced twice in DiscountRef.

Comment: @Lmu92 The Amount is "Percentage" amount so "Clearance" is a 75% discount. I will add a new column to DisRef to show which discounts are active. Currently all PCats types are under the effect of discounts. No RefType Product is currently under a discount (But was under a discount at some time). Also multiple discounts can be active so there could be three DisId active at the same time I.E. 3 products are under a 10% discount but are not related in category.

Comment: @MarcusM - is your desired results table the complete set of results for the dataset you have provided or a snippet to illustrate what you need for the output?

Comment: @DotThoughts Yes it's the complete set with the provided information. So any query made based on that data needs to return that table. If more rows where added then of course the desired table will change. Sorry for being so verbose.